# Tornado endpoint matching

Tags: tornado

I have been trying to find some documentation from tornado about endpoint matching priorities and I couldnt find anything..I wonder what is the expected behaviour of tornado doing endpoint matching.

Example:

```
def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application(
            (r"/api/v1/tree/", test1),
            (
                r"/api/v1/?(?P<variable1>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?(?P<variable2>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?",
                test2,
            ),
            (r"/api/v1/garden/tree/" + r"([^/]+)/", test3)
            ]
     )
```

In particular I wonder if the 1st and 3rd method will be ever called or if the second call will make the others to be ignored.

Comment: Whichever match is found first, tornado will call that handler.

Comment: @xyres if I call api/v1/tree it will also match the 2nd one, so what I wonder if what is the priority for the matching to happen

Comment: `api/v1/tree` will not match the first handler because it doesn't have a slash at the end. But if you call `api/v1/tree/`, it will call the first handler because Tornado won't try to match other endpoints after a match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rules are considered in order and the first match is used. So in this case the `/api/v1/tree/` rule will always be considered. The `/api/v1/garden/tree` rule should probably be moved above the second rule, although it's hard to read the regular expression to determine whether there is a real conflict there.